# How to delete row in Excel with protected columns and VBA auto filling columns

Tags: excel, vba

I need help with an Excel spreadsheet.  Here are the things I need to do.

4 columns will need to be protected. 1 will contain who entered the row.  1 will contain the date row was created.  1 will contain who updated the row last.  And 1 will contain last date row was updated.

For this, I already have a simple but working code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Row = 1 Then Exit Sub
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Cells(Target.Row, "AD").Value = Environ$("UserName")
  Cells(Target.Row, "AE").Value = Date      
  If IsEmpty(Cells(Target.Row, "AG")) Then
      Cells(Target.Row, "AG").Value = Environ$("UserName")
      Cells(Target.Row, "AF").Value = Date
  End If      
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Now the problem is deleting a row.  I found a VBA code while googling but when it deletes the row the code above executes and fill the 4 columns with data.

Can anyone show me a code to handle the delete please?

Thanks,

Rick..

Comment: Why can't you just set a global boolean or something that's only true when your row deleting code is operating, and then only run the worksheet_change code when that boolean is false?

Comment: Okay that sound good.  I will give that a try.  I am just jumping into VBA in Excel and have not used this for a long time.  Have to get familiar again.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Josh mentioned in his comment, a boolean will work. However you should probably use the built in Event "blocker".

Before you delete the Row(s) disable events to make sure the Worksheet_Change is not triggered. After all changes are done, enable events again.

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
'Delete stuff
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Comment: Hi Josh.  I tried the global variable flag and it worked.  However, it looks like the setting the EnableEvents true/false is the proper way of doing it.  I am currently using the Worksheet_SelectionChange event to protect/unprotect the sheet.  This allows the deletion of a row to work.  Do you know if a better way to allow delete on a sheet with protected columns?

Comment: Protected columns? as in the worksheet is protected from some changes with a password? If that's the case you need to unprotect the sheet, make the changes, protect again. ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName").Unprotect "Password" 'delete stuff ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName").Protect "Password"